# How to measure string width and specify language script

Tags: c#, gdi+

I've been successfully measuring strings with System.Drawing.Graphics with this (simplified) code snippet:

```
    var cachedFont = cachedFont = new System.Drawing.Font(pfc.Families[0], line.FontSize, fontStyle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(new[] { new CharacterRange(0, line.Text.Length) });
    var regions = graphics.Value.MeasureCharacterRanges(line.Text, cachedFont, new Rectangle(0, 0, 10000, 0), format);

    double result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < regions.Length; i++)
    {
        var region = regions[i];
        result += region.GetBounds(graphics.Value).Width;
        region.Dispose();
    }

    return result;
```

However, I need to support OpenType layout which might have multiple language variations for a specific character, depending on the Language script (e.g. Arabic, Thai, CJK scripts, etc.)

It's safe to assume that the measurements are incorrect when a glyph substitution takes place when measuring strings with the system's default script.

Does System.Drawing.Graphics supports different scripts? How do I define them?

Comment: This can't go anywhere, System.Drawing does not support OpenType.

Comment: Was afraid of that. Any suggestions ?